# How to determine at launcher runtime whether the JRE is bundled locally or not?

Tags: java, install4j

I'm thinking maybe check if `java.home` starts with the current execution path, e.g.

```
<install.dir>/jre
```

But, launchers can be configured to change the working directory, or they can be placed somewhere else but the installation root. Also unsure where the jre would be placed on MacOS.

Is there a more reliable way to do this?

Context: For our custom update mechanism I need this information to determine the correct mediafile (with or without bundled JRE).

Comment: If you have two distribution packages already then why not add this configuration information to the package as part of the deployment?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, that would be an option. But whenever possible, I prefer not to add to our installer configuration complexity (already very high). Also, it is possible to delete the bundled JRE from the installation manually. And our update servers already expect a query parameter specifying with/without JRE, which we cannot change because of existing installations from previous years.

Answer (score 1):

Found more info on the [help page for JRE bundles](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/v/8.0/help/doc/concepts/jreBundles.html):

[image]

So my next attempt would be:

```
String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
String installDir = (String) com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables
    .getInstallerVariable(InstallerVariables.VARIABLE_INSTALLATION_DIR);
String contentDir = (String) com.install4j.api.launcher.Variables
    .getInstallerVariable(InstallerVariables.VARIABLE_CONTENT_DIR);

javaHome = new File(javaHome).getCanonicalPath();
installDir = new File(installDir).getCanonicalPath();
contentDir = new File(contentDir).getCanonicalPath();

boolean bundledJre = javaHome.startsWith(installDir) || javaHome.startsWith(contentDir);
```